# How can I authenticate any database with given username and password in Mongo Java Driver 2.13.0?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, mongodb-java, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

Previously I could use `db.authenticate(String username, char[] password)` method. With 2.13.0, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no replacement for db.authenticate(). The driver will use the credentials provided and make sure the connections are authenticated as they are created.

Based on [this mongodb-user discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/5apv3wK-pBQ/DnJPw5h9eEEJ) the Java Driver team is open to discussions on what the real need for the db.authenticate(...) method.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
>
> MongoCredential mongoCred =
>   MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential(String username, String
>   dbName, char[] password);

and create mongoclient using mongocredentials

com.mongodb.MongoClient.MongoClient(List seeds, List 
 credentialsList, MongoClientOptions options)

Comment: I know about MongoCredential. I just want to authenticate database against username or password as I  mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

**We can have user-password based authentication for databases, in that case we need to provide authorization credentials like below for new version.**

```
MongoCredential journaldevAuth = MongoCredential.createPlainCredential("pankaj", "journaldev", "pankaj123".toCharArray());
    MongoCredential testAuth = MongoCredential.createPlainCredential("pankaj", "test", "pankaj123".toCharArray());
    List<MongoCredential> auths = new ArrayList<MongoCredential>();
    auths.add(journaldevAuth);
    auths.add(testAuth);

    ServerAddress serverAddress = new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017);
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(serverAddress, auths);
```

**If you are using older versions, you need to provide authentication details after getting the DB object like below**

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("journaldev");
boolean auth = db.authenticate("pankaj", "pankaj123".toCharArray());
```