# Connecting mongoDB with java

Tags: java, mongodb, connection

i have to try creating connection class using java to connect with mongoDB database, everything seems okay, but i always get authenticate error message

this the error line

```
boolean auth = db.authenticate("aku", "kamu".toCharArray());
```

[image]

Comment: any solutions guys?

Comment: check your project setup, it show that you IDE did not find the symbol, means some jar is missing, if jar is their, than it is not avalabe to IDE.

Comment: can you give me link to download that jar you have on your pc?
i'll try to using another jar..
if its still failed, can you suggest me another IDE to compile java application and java web?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I authenticate any database with given username and password in Mongo Java Driver 2.13.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343795/how-can-i-authenticate-any-database-with-given-username-and-password-in-mongo-ja)

Comment: i am newbie on mongoDB, i cant understand what is credential, can u make it clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check whether you are using MongoDB 2.X or 3.X driver.

The API `DB.authenticate(String username, char[] passwd)` is no longer exists in 3.X driver. Please see http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/driver/reference/connecting/authenticating/ on how to authenticate with the 3.X driver.

Comment: i think will be better if i change to the 2.x API :)
it so confusing

Comment: thanks so much dude :) it works on me,i change the API to 2.x version...